# Starcraft 2 Legacy of the Void - unlock heroes for co-op

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to play SC 2 co-op with the locked heroes. When I select them, it says that the hero is included in the Legacy of the Void expansion (except for Abathur that has to be bought separately).

I was wondering if I buy only a Legacy of the Void CD key from a third-party key reseller, will I be able to play the locked heroes on the EU server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay to buy Starcraft 2 keys from resellers (and often cheaper than from Blizzard directly).

After they send you the key, you activate in on your Blizzard account and the account gains that game license - the same end result you get when you just purchase from Blizzard.

As been said, yes, you only need Starcraft 2: Legacy of the Void to play Swann, Zagara, Vorazun, and Karax.